# Scala: Cool way to manage sequential execution of Futures?

Tags: scala, future

I'm trying to write a data module in Scala.

While loading entire data in parallel, some data depends on other data, so execution sequence has to be managed in efficient way.

For example in code, I keep a map with name of data and manifest

```
val dataManifestMap = Map(
  "foo" -> manifest[String],
  "bar" -> manifest[Int],
  "baz" -> manifest[Int],
  "foobar" -> manifest[Set[String]], // need to be executed after "foo" and "bar" is ready
  "foobarbaz" -> manifest[String], // need to be executed after "foobar" and "baz" is ready
)
```

These data will be stored in a mutable hash map

```
private var dataStorage = new mutable.HashMap[String, Future[Any]]()
```

There are some code that will load data

```
def loadAllData(): Future[Unit] = {
  Future.join(
    (dataManifestMap map {
      case (data, m) => loadData(data, m) } // function has all the string matching and loading stuff
    ).toSeq
  )    
}

def loadData[T](data: String, m: Manifest[T]): Future[Unit] = {
  val d = data match {
    case "foo" => Future.value("foo")
    case "bar" => Future.value(3)
    case "foobar" => // do something with dataStorage("foo") and dataStorage("bar")
    ... // and so forth (in a real example it would be much more complicated for sure)
  }

  d flatMap { 
    dVal => { this.synchronized { dataStorage(data) = dVal }; Future.value(Unit) }
  }
}
```

This way, I cannot make sure "foobar" is loaded when "foo" and "bar" is ready, and so forth.

How can I manage this in a "cool" way, since I might have hundreds of different data?

It would be "awesome" if I could have some kind of data structure that has all the info about something has to be loaded after something, and sequential execution can be handled by flatMap in a neat way.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: May be using Actors would be more to the point here?

Comment: Sorry for the crappy sudo code. Also, all I need is making sure that "foo" and "bar" is ready when trying to load "foobar". So the solution does not necessarily need to be related to sequential execution of Futures. It can be using Promise properly, or anything that could serve the purpose. Thank you.

Comment: that's exactly where stateful actors can be useful.

Comment: @Ashalynd Thank you for your suggestion! I'm still not sure what design I should use though :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All things being equal, I'd tend to use `for` comprehensions. For example:

```
def findBucket: Future[Bucket[Empty]] = ???
def fillBucket(bucket: Bucket[Empty]): Future[Bucket[Water]] = ???
def extinguishOvenFire(waterBucket: Bucket[Water]): Future[Oven] = ???
def makeBread(oven: Oven): Future[Bread] = ???
def makeSoup(oven: Oven): Future[Soup] = ???
def eatSoup(soup: Soup, bread: Bread): Unit = ???


def doLunch = {
  for (bucket <- findBucket;
       filledBucket <- fillBucket(bucket);
       oven <- extinguishOvenFire(filledBucket);
       soupFuture = makeSoup(oven);
       breadFuture = makeBread(oven);
       soup <- soupFuture;
       bread <- breadFuture) {
    eatSoup(soup, bread)
  }
}
```

This chains futures together, and calls the relevant methods once dependencies are satisfied. Note that we use `=` in the `for` comprehension to allow us to start two `Futures` at the same time. As it stands, `doLunch` returns `Unit`, but if you replace the last few lines with:

```
// ..snip..
       bread <- breadFuture) yield {
    eatSoup(soup, bread)
    oven
  }
}
```

Then it will return `Future[Oven]` - which might be useful if you want to use the oven for something else after lunch.

As for your code, my first though would be that you should consider [Spray cache](http://spray.io/documentation/1.1-SNAPSHOT/spray-caching/), as it looks like it might fit your requirements. If not, my next thought would be to replace the [Stringly typed](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/07/new-programming-jargon.html) interface you've currently got and go with something based on typed method calls:

```
private def save[T](key: String)(value: Future[T]) = this.synchronized {
  dataStorage(key) = value
  value
}

def loadFoo = save("foo"){Future("foo")}
def loadBar = save("bar"){Future(3)}
def loadFooBar = save("foobar"){
  for (foo <- loadFoo;
       bar <- loadBar) yield foo + bar // Or whatever
}
def loadBaz = save("baz"){Future(200L)}
def loadAll = {
  val topLevelFutures = Seq(loadFooBar, loadBaz)
  // Use standard library function to combine futures
  Future.fold(topLevelFutures)(())((u,f) => ())
}

// I don't consider this method necessary, but if you've got a legacy API to support...
def loadData[T](key: String)(implicit manifest: Manifest[T]) = {
  val future = key match {
      case "foo" => loadFoo
      case "bar" => loadBar
      case "foobar" => loadFooBar
      case "baz" => loadBaz
      case "all" => loadAll
  }
  future.mapTo[T]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm still not sure I should implement your design or use Actors...

Comment: Maybe you could tell us a little more about the specifics of your problem. For example, does the sequence of tasks need to be modifiable at run-time (possibly by non-technical users), or is it OK if it's fixed at compile-time? Can the correct order somehow be determined by inspecting the data? What sort of data are we actually talking about, and what sort of code is used to load it? These things might suggest a specific design.

Comment: 1. No, it doesn't have to be modifiable. Sequence will be fixed. Although, other than loading entire data at the beginning, there is a possibility that "foobar" can be reloaded separately during running time (data that depends on other data) so in this case, "foo" and "bar" must be loaded beforehand when loading "foobar" is requested. 2. Inspecting the data won't be helpful when determining the order 3. Data will consist Set of Int, Map, and so forth. Data will be loaded from redis, MySQL, and msgpack cached data. All code are written in Scala at this point.

Comment: (To elaborate on 1) loadData[T] could be called separately, not only in loadAllData. So when loadData("foobar") is called and "foo" and "bar" is not loaded, we should load both "foo" and "bar" before loading "foobar"! Hope this helps!

Comment: This sounds a bit like a cache. Would that be fair? And would you consider using something like spray-cache (http://spray.io/documentation/1.1-SNAPSHOT/spray-caching/)?

Comment: It looks nice, but since I've been using Twitter Future, I might consider implementing it in Twitter/Finagle way. Thanks!

Comment: Ahh! That explains why `Future.value` wouldn't compile for me. I've been using standard library `Future`s.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your sincere help!